# How to add a missing character in the value

Tags: informatica

There is a file which has a column containing free text and some words of a sentence are enclosed in single quotes but sometimes user forgets to close the open quote with a closing quote, ex: My name is 'XXX and I am visiting my native place 'YYY' for 'ZZZ. So here we have two words that have missing closing quote on 2 words. Requirement is to find & add a missing close quote. How can we achieve this in Informatica.

Comment: Are you only looking at single words, no spaces? Could any of the words contain single quotes e.g. "it's"?

Comment: @NickW i think in case of it's, logic shouldn't replace anything. Idea is if a word starts with ' it must end with another '. I think OP need to use JAVA Transformation and for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if there's an even number of single quotes in the string. So, first calculate the number of single quotes. Problem is, you can't use single quotes in functions - so instead use the [CHR function](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/data-services/10-1/transformation-language-reference/functions/chr.html) to get the single quote:`CHR(39)`. Now, it's possible to do the count as a difference between the original string lenght and one with single quotes removed. Wrapping that in modulo by 2 function will tell if there is a missing quote or not:

```
v_missing_quotes = MOD(LENGTH('column')- LENGTH(replace('column', 'CHR(39)', '')), 2)
```

Now, if quote are missing, just add it:

```
out_with_quotes = IIF(v_missing_quotes, column || 'CHR(39)', column)
```

Comment: Its nice solution but i think this wont cover OP's use case. OP's input is `'XXX and I am visiting my native place 'YYY' for 'ZZZ`, this has 4 quotes. Pls note quote can be absent from anywhere so we can concat quote in the end always. I believe java is the only answer.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. We can check quote count, we can check if there's opening and ending quote and... that's about it. If we need to check if word startting after quote has and ending quote, Java Transformation is the only option I see.